# Entity Framework - Error on db.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework to create a database and write to it from my model and controller.  I am getting an error on the line "DB.SaveChanges();".  The error states: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."  Then the inner exceptions states: "Invalid object name 'dbo.ContactModel'."  I have looked through all the SO posts with a similar question but none seemed to fix my issue.  I will post the code that I think is relevant to the issue.  Let me know if there is more needed.

My ContactContext.cs class:

```
using newBestPlay.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace newBestPlay.DAL
{
    public class ContactContext : DbContext
    {

        public ContactContext() : base("BestPlay")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ContactModel> Contacts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

And my < connectionStrings > in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Contacts.mdf;Initial Catalog=Contacts;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="BestPlay" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
< /connectionStrings >
```

Here is the index post method in the controller:

```
// POST: Contact/Index
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "ID,name,address,city,state,zip,phone,fax,email,requestType,emailAlerts,message")] ContactModel contactModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        contactModel.name = ToTitleCase(contactModel.name);
        contactModel.address = ToTitleCase(contactModel.address);
        contactModel.city = ToTitleCase(contactModel.city);
        db.Contacts.Add(contactModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["Message"] = "Thank you for your input.  If requested, we will contact you soon.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(contactModel);
}
```

I would think that would be all that is needed.  Let me know if more code is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out with some help narrowing it down from Yuval Itzchakov.  My table did not exist and I thought the Entity Framework was supposed to automatically create it for me.  Well it wasn't.  The actual query that was failing was this: `INSERT [dbo].[Contacts]([name], [address], [city], [state], [zip], [phone], [fax], [email], [requestType], [emailAlerts], [message])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10)
SELECT [ID]
FROM [dbo].[Contacts]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()`

So it was trying to run a select on a non-existant table.  I figured out that I had to add this line into my ContactContext class in the constructor:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ContactContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ContactContext>());
```

That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

If you're overriding `OnModelCreating`, you need to pass the mapping to your `DbModelBuilder`, as the entity name and the table in your database don't match:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<ContactModel>().ToTable("Contacts");
}
```

Comment: I added that second line in.  Now I get "Invalid object name 'dbo.Contacts'." as the inner exception.

Comment: Is your table called `Contacts`?

Comment: That is what I want it to be called when it is created, yes.

Comment: And does your `ContactModel` map exactly to your current database column?

Comment: It is supposed to create the table columns dynamically from the model.

Comment: Try deleting the existing `Contacts` table and running your query again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78200/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-yuval-itzchakov).